# Can I use KNN for inference?

Tags: clustering, k-nearest-neighbour

So, I have a dataset with several columns and one output. However, I'm not trying to predict anything, I'm trying to understand each variable relation with the output. Let's say I have a dataset with cars from a store. Column A is the car id, column B is the color, column C is the price, column D is the brand - which may have lots of uniques values - and column E is the answer for it being sold or not. 
Can KNN help me with understanding which characteristics are more important for the output to be 1 or 0? Or should I use another algorithm?

Answer (score 4):

As a recap, what $k$-NN algorithm does when making prediction for the $\mathbf{x}_i, y_i$ sample is:

> 1. for all the $\mathbf{x}_j$ training samples, calculate the distance between them and the target sample $d(\mathbf{x}_j,
>     \mathbf{x}_i)$,
> 2. take $k$ training samples within the closest distance to $\mathbf{x}_i$, let's call this subset $\mathcal{K}$,
> 3. calculate the prediction by using some aggregate statistic, e.g. mean $\hat y_i = \tfrac{1}{k} \sum_{j \in \mathcal{K}} y_j$.

If this is a regression problem, you'd take $\hat y_i$ as is, for classification if the labels are zeros and ones, this mean would be a rough approximation of the probability of belonging to target class, so for hard classifications you'd take some cut-off value to make the classification decision.

Notice that this algorithm *can* make the decisions for each of the samples based on different variables. During preprocessing data for $k$-NN we usually normalize the data, so that they all have similar scales, so that any of the variables would not dominate the distance metric, but they would vary on case-by-case basis. So by itself, this algorithm *would not* tell you anything about the "overall" influence of the individual variables. It simply does not learn any "general patterns" from the data.

What $k$-NN would give you is the *"customers who bought this item also bought"* kind of answer, by pointing to other samples that were similar to the $\mathbf{x}_i$ sample. To do this, you do not need to make classifications, just sort the samples by distance to $\mathbf{x}_i$.

Of course, you could use one of the algorithms for machine learning interpretability (see e.g. the [*Interpretable Machine Learning* book by Christoph Molnar](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/)), as for *any other* algorithm, but I'm not sure if this would make much sense in case of $k$-NN for the reasons stated above.